# Conditional expectation of a stochastic process in filtered space

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-probability

It was suggested* to me that if we have a stochastic process with independent increments, and $T > t$, then $$ E(X_{T-t}| \mathcal{F}_t) = X_{T-t} $$ where $\mathcal{F}_t$ is the filtration at time $t$. This relation allegedly holds because $X_{T-t}$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable.

I am unable to reconcile this relation. I have had some experience with filtrations in discrete models, so as far as I know, the only processes $X_T$ that are $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable when $T>t$, are the *predictable* processes, for example  a deterministic interest rate process.

Could someone help me elucidate this relation?

$*$ [Equation involving expectations of Levy processes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716242/equation-involving-expectations-of-levy-processes)

Comment: Does $X_t$, $t=1,2,\ldots$ happen to be a martingale? Or just a general stochastic process? If it is a martingale then we know that $E(X_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}) = X_n$.

Comment: It is not necessarily a martingale. As mentioned, this relation is supposed to be derived only form the fact that the process has independent increments.

Comment: Nowhere in the solution to the other question do they say that. It is only when you miscopied the answer and asked for confirmation that, for a reason I cannot fathom, the OP agreed with this (wrong) assertion.

Comment: The relation $E(X_{T-t}|\mathcal{F}_t) = E(X_{T-t})$ is implicitly used to derive equation (2) in the answer. That is what I asked about in the comments, but you are correct that the relation I presented here is the one that was mentioned (maybe mistakingly) by the answerer only in the comments afterwards.

Comment: "The relation E(XT−t|Ft)=E(XT−t) is implicitly used to derive equation (2) in the answer. " Absolutely not, neither implicitely nor explicitely. Would you be taking $X_{T-t}$ for $X_T-X_t$? First and foremost, "the relation (you) presented here is the one that" YOU introduced in the comments, not the OP.

Comment: The relation I asked about here was never mentioned by me in the comments. And $E(X_{T-t}|\mathcal{F}_t)=E(X_{T-t})$ is indeed used in the answer, by first using the fact that $X_{T-t}=X_T -X_t$ by stationary increments and then applying the relation

Comment: No it is not (you are misreading again) and the stationarity of the increments does not mean that $X_{T-t}=X_T-X_t$ (you are confusing identity in distribution and identity almost surely). (Unrelated: Please use @, unless you want to avoid that I read your comment.)

Comment: @Did Okay so what you mean is that the relation used is instead$$ E(X_T - X_t | \mathcal{F}_t )= E(X_T - X_t) $$
?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elucidate relations, let's take a brownian motion $B_t$ as an example and look carefully when we use which property. When looking up the definition of brownian motion here (http://www.randomservices.org/random/brown/Standard.html) we get the definitions of stationarity increments and independant increments at the same time.

From the independancy of increments we can deduce the relation
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[B_{T}-B_{t}|\mathcal{F}_t]=B_{T}-B_{t}.
\end{equation}
From the stationarity of the increments we further know
\begin{equation}
(B_{T}-B_{t}) \tilde{} B_{T-t}
\end{equation}
and could deduce
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[B_{T}-B_{t}]=\mathbb{E}[B_{T-t}].
\end{equation}
Brownian motion also has other properties, like e.g. the Martingale property, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[B_{t_2}|\mathcal{F}_{t_1}]=B_{t_1}.
\end{equation}
for t_1<=t_2. But your suggestion is wrong and the brownian motion serves as counter example: Assume your equation would hold for brownian motion. Take $T=3$ and $t=1$:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[B_{2}|\mathcal{F}_1]=B_{2}.
\end{equation}
That contradicts the martingale property, since $B_1\neq B_2$ with probability $>0$ (Exercise!).